# JavaScript reassigning values is not working

Tags: javascript, html

When I am trying to reassign a value of an input box to a different value in JavaScript nothing gets changed. I have made an alert to make sure the variable is valid and I also tried adding a `toString()` method.

```js
function assignWords(){
    alert("word one " + wordOne);
    document.getElementById("word1").value = wordOne;
    document.getElementById("word2").value = wordTwo.toString();
    document.getElementById("word3").value = wordThree.toString();
    document.getElementById("word4").value = wordFour.toString();
    document.getElementById("word5").value = wordFive.toString();
}
```

```html
<div class="PlayGame"> 
    <h2>Word Scramble USA</h2>
    <input id="myText" type="text"  placeholder="begin to type" onkeyup="checkWords()" />    
    <input id="word1"  type="submit" name="word1" value="">
    <input id="word2"  type="submit" name="word2" value="" disabled>
    <input id="word3"  type="submit" name="word3" value="" disabled>
    <input id="word4"  type="submit" name="word4" value="" disabled>
    <input id="word5"  type="submit" name="word5" value="" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `assignWords` called? Where are wordOne, wordTwo etc declared?

Comment: Yes they are. The alert will spit out the word it should be.

Comment: You are not calling  'assignWords', you are calling 'checkWords'.

Comment: lol ... "yes they are" does not answer ***where** are they declared* - and the code you've posted doesn't help ... check the browser developer tools console for errors you probably have

Answer (score 2):

U should call your function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="PlayGame">
      <h2>Word Scramble USA</h2>
      <input
        id="myText"
        type="text"
        placeholder="begin to type"
        onkeyup="checkWords()"
      />
      <input id="word1" type="submit" name="word1" value="" />
      <input id="word2" type="submit" name="word2" value="" disabled />
      <input id="word3" type="submit" name="word3" value="" disabled />
      <input id="word4" type="submit" name="word4" value="" disabled />
      <input id="word5" type="submit" name="word5" value="" disabled />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function assignWords() {
      document.getElementById("word1").value = "Need";
      document.getElementById("word2").value = "for";
      document.getElementById("word3").value = "function";
      document.getElementById("word4").value = "call";
      document.getElementById("word5").value = wordFive.toString();
    }
    assignWords();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah I have removed alert

Comment: @h.man96 - ***where** are you calling the function* - not in the ***code** you posted*

Answer (score 0):

@h.man96

Try this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function assignWords(){
 var wordOne = document.getElementById("word1").value;
    var wordTwo = document.getElementById("word2").value;
    var wordThree = document.getElementById("word3").value;
    var wordFour = document.getElementById("word4").value;
    var wordFive = document.getElementById("word5").value;
     
    alert("word one " + wordOne);
}
</script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="PlayGame"> 
    <h2>Word Scramble USA</h2>
    <input id="myText" type="text"  placeholder="begin to type" onkeyup="checkWords()" />    
    <input id="word1"  type="submit" name="word1" value="hii" onclick="assignWords()">
    <input id="word2"  type="submit" name="word2" value="hello" disabled>
    <input id="word3"  type="submit" name="word3" value="how r u ??" disabled>
    <input id="word4"  type="submit" name="word4" value="who r u ??" disabled>
    <input id="word5"  type="submit" name="word5" value="i am fine" disabled>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.